# What is rank, numIteraions and lambda in ALS.train()?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

I am new to spark machine learning. I'm experimenting with **Collaborative Filtering** using **ALS algorithm**. In this algorithm I need some clarifications about **rank, numIterations and lambda** parameters which is used for training the algorithm. And I need to know how to tune this algorithm for the smallest and largest datasets to produce the improved predictions. Could somebody explain this?

Comment: This always depends on the data. Use cross-validation to chose these. Some intuitions (usually right): higher rank: more data needed; higher rank: more regulization /lambda needed.

Comment: Got an idea. Thanks... @sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **numBlocks** is the number of blocks used to parallelize computation (set
> to -1 to auto-configure).
>
> **rank** is the number of features to use (also referred to as the number of latent factors).
>
> **iterations** is the number of iterations of ALS to run. ALS typically converges to a reasonable solution in 20 iterations or less.

`numBlocks` has to do with the blocks of the matrix.

`rank` are the hidden factors, the number of features you would like to use. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729656/what-is-rank-in-als-machine-learning-algorithm-in-apache-spark-mllib).

*iterations* is the number of the repeatitions you want to perform. The parameter's name is *not* numIterations.

Read more about ALS [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Alternating-Least-Squares-method-in-recommendation-systems-And-why-does-this-algorithm-work-intuition-behind-this).

---

> I need to know how to tune the training parameters to increase the prediction with the less and high number of datas?

This always depends on the data. Use cross-validation to chose these.

Comment: Thanks gsamaras. I have the basic idea of ALS is working on matrix factorization model. I need to know how to tune the training parameters to increase the prediction with the less and high number of datas?

Comment: I agree with Sascha on this, updated my answer. Good luck!